# Microsoft Partner Center SDK. IAzureUtilizationCollection.Query method get fail on Next page

Tags: c#, azure, billing

I am using Partner Center SDK "Get a customer's utilization records for Azure" function. Data must be requested page by page. But I have error when request Next page after first.

This is my code and result:

```
    var partnerOperations = UserPartnerOperations;
    var toTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    var fromTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-10);
    var utilizationRecords = partnerOperations.Customers[customerId].Subscriptions[subscriptionId]
        .Utilization.Azure.Query(
            fromTime,
            toTime,
            size: 10,
            granularity: AzureUtilizationGranularity.Daily);
    var utilizationRecordEnumerator = partnerOperations.Enumerators.Utilization.Azure.Create(utilizationRecords);
    var pageNumber = 1;

    while (utilizationRecordEnumerator.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PageNumber: {0}", pageNumber++);
        var page = utilizationRecordEnumerator.Current;
        foreach (var utilizationRecord in page.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UsageStartTime:{0:s} UsageEndTime:{1:s} Name:{2} Quantity:{3}", 
                utilizationRecord.UsageStartTime.UtcDateTime, 
                utilizationRecord.UsageEndTime.UtcDateTime, 
                utilizationRecord.Resource.Name, 
                utilizationRecord.Quantity);
        }
        utilizationRecordEnumerator.Next(); // Line 239
    }


Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.Exceptions.PartnerException : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.Exceptions.PartnerException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PartnerService.SynchronousExecute(Func`1 operation)
   at MSPControl.Providers.o365.Api.PartnerCenterApiClient.GetAzureUtilizationRecordsOrigin(String customerId, String subscriptionId, DateTimeOffset startTime, DateTimeOffset endTime, UtilizationGranularity granularity) in E:\_Projects\MSPControl\MSPControl\Sources\MSPControl.Providers.o365.Api\PartnerCenterApiClient.cs:**line 239**
   at MSPControl.Providers.o365.Api.Tests.PartnerCenterApiClientTests.SaveUtilizationRecordsTest() in E:\_Projects\MSPControl.Tests\MSPControl.Providers.MicrosoftOnline.Tests\PartnerCenterApiClientTests.cs:line 82

PageNumber: 1
UsageStartTime:2017-01-13T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 Name:Standard Small App Service Hours Quantity:3.0
UsageStartTime:2017-01-13T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 Name:Basic Database Days Quantity:0.166666666666667
UsageStartTime:2017-01-13T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 Name:Free App Service Quantity:0.004032
UsageStartTime:2017-01-13T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 Name:Basic Database Days Quantity:0.208333333333333
UsageStartTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-15T00:00:00 Name:Standard Small App Service Hours Quantity:24.0
UsageStartTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-15T00:00:00 Name:Basic Database Days Quantity:0.833333333333333
UsageStartTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-15T00:00:00 Name:Free App Service Quantity:0.032256
UsageStartTime:2017-01-14T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-15T00:00:00 Name:Basic Database Days Quantity:1.0
UsageStartTime:2017-01-15T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-16T00:00:00 Name:Standard Small App Service Hours Quantity:21.0
UsageStartTime:2017-01-15T00:00:00 UsageEndTime:2017-01-16T00:00:00 Name:Free App Service Quantity:0.028224
```